# Find the integral: $\int_0^{1/2} x \sin(\pi x^2)\,dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{1/2}  x \sin(\pi x^2)\,dx$$

I have: $-\cos (1/4) -1$.

Comment: what is $\int_{0}^{1}/2x\sin(\pi x^2)\,dx$?

Comment: I have edited the formula to what I assume that you meant. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: It is correct, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1/2}x\sin(\pi x^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1/2}2\pi x\sin(\pi x^2)\,dx = -\left.\frac{1}{2\pi}\cos(\pi x^2)\right|_{0}^{1/2}=\frac{\cos 0-\cos(\pi/4)}{2\pi}=\color{red}{\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4\pi}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake somewhere along the way, although I don't know where without seeing your steps. Letting $u = \pi x^2$ we have $\text{d}u = 2\pi x \text{d}x \implies x\text{d}x =\frac{\text{d}u}{2\pi} $ which means our integral becomes $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \sin(u) \text{d}u = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(-\cos(u)\Big\vert_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\ = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \end{align}$$ which differs from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the integral $\int x\sin(\pi x^2)\,dx$ set $t=\pi x^2$ and we have $2\pi xdx=dt$

Answer (score 0):

$ u = x^2$, $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$

Then we get $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}\frac{1}{2}\sin(\pi u) du$$

which comes to $\frac{1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}{2\pi} = \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4\pi}$